# Can Arduino Mega2560 Use this 24VDC Relay?

Tags: arduino-mega, relay

Can a Arduino MEGA 2560 R3 provide enough current out of its pin to activate the [Songle srd-24vdc-sl-c relay](http://www.hebertech.com/view/3778-songle-srd-24vdc.pdf)? Will powering the Arduino with an external power supply help?

[image]

Comment: Please avoid proving links (for the datasheet) that will require people to download and run an executable for viewing, it's the open door for virus and spams! I have found the same datasheet as PDF here: http://www.datasheet4u.com/download_new.php?id=720559

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can higher current devices (motors, solenoids, lights, etc.) be controlled by an Arduino?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-higher-current-devices-motors-solenoids-lights-etc-be-controlled-b)

Comment: I don't consider this question a duplicate as the problem here is voltage-related in fact. However, the solutions may be similar.

Comment: As I know there is a 5Vdc one from the same manufacturer....

Comment: The 5V relay is a better/simpler option, but still requires an extra transistor (and flyback diode) to switch the relay current.

Answer (score 1):

This relay cannot be **directly** commanded by any Arduino because its coil require **24V voltage** to be able to switch the contact; Arduino Mega pins output voltage is **5V**.

Regarding **current**, the **relay coil needs 15mA** ("high sensitivity" model) **or 18.7mA** (standard model), that would be OK for an Arduino Mega pin (**max current = 40mA**).

Anyway, you would have to add some circuit to adapt voltage between the Arduino pin and the relay. For this, first of all **you will need to get a second power supply** (in addition to the Arduino 5V supply used for Arduino) that can supply 24V.

Then you could use a [MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) transistor between the Arduino pin and the relay. A MOSFET is often used in so-called **Solid State Relay** ([SSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_relay)) because it can almost do the same as a coil relay but is 100% electronic-based (no moving parts); however, contrarily to a coil relay, it does not provide galvanic isolation between the input and the output circuits.

You can check out [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-higher-current-devices-motors-solenoids-lights-etc-be-controlled-b) to find out further information on MOSFET.

Personnally, I would rather replace that relay with a 5V relay model, as that would make the circuit simpler, and would remove the need for a second power supply.

Comment: No, a MOSFET is never called an SSR, these are entirely different devices. A MOSFET has no galvanic separation between input and "output".

Comment: Well according to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_relay), it's not obvious an SSR has to provide galvanic separation. Also, it mentions a "A SSR based on a single MOSFET, ..., works well for DC loads.". I think we might argue about it, but I admit that provided SSR examples don't look like MOSFET :-) I'll update my answer.

Comment: I had a chat at EE.SE and apparently a single MOSFET called SSR is uncommon, but it does sometimes appear in literature.